# Change char by index

Tags: c, clang

Trying to change char by index:

```
char *p = "test";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    p[i] = 50;
}
printf("%s\n", p);//test
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You’re trying to change a character literal which is read-only

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: You probably mean ["string literal"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), not "character literal".

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Sorry, yes, that’s exactly what I meant of course

Answer (score 1):

you cannot change a literal,

```
char*p="test";
```

doesnt copy the literal. You should do

```
char p[] = "test";
```

or

```
#include <string.h>
....
char *p = strdup("test");
```

if you want to deal with a pointer rather than a char array.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
char *p = "test";
```

will make the pointer `p` point to the [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) `"test"`.

String literals are read-only. Attempting to modify them will invoke undefined behavior.

If you want `"test"` to be writable, then you must allocate (writable) memory for it, for example by declaring an array:

```
char arr[] = "test";
```

That line is equivalent to

```
char arr[5] = "test";
```

which creates an array of 5 characters and initializes the first 4 characters to `"test"` and initializes the 5<sup>th</sup> character to a null terminating character.

Now that you have allocated memory for the string, you can write to it at will, for example you could write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    arr[i] = 50;
}
```

Or you could make a pointer `p` point to the array, and use the pointer for accessing the string, as you did in the code in the question:

```
char *p = arr;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    p[i] = 50;
}
```